# Unwrapping a function 12 calls deep

Tags: c, function

so a block is code is wrapped by a function. Function A calls function B. Unwrapping function B would be to put the code from function B inside function A.

My question is: I have A calls B calls C calls ... 12 times. So  i have a call graph 12 functions deep( from an open source library that decodes images) and i want to make the decoding streamable by unwrapping the 12 functions to get to the loop that actually decodes the image. By doing this i can tell the decoder to not decode the whole image at once but to do small steps whenever i tell it do.

If anyone knows or has ever had such a problem, please let me know of any good design patern.

PS: language is C.

Comment: Way too vague to answer. Is the code short enough to post it here ? Otherwise, you should take a stab at it, starting from the innermost function, and eventually post a more focused question if you get definitely stuck.

Comment: Doesn't really sound like the functions themselves are the problem, but rather some hard-coded assumption of how much that should be executed. Anyway, far too vague indeed for anyone to answer.

Comment: If you're dealing with complex external libraries not adapted to streaming work then you're generally speaking in trouble. Coroutines from a blocking I/O hook may be about the only "general" solution.

Comment: yes i ma trying to modify a library to be able to be streamed, for performance issues, so that i can have a smooth 60 fps draw without stutterng, and there is no possibility of threading. I am using a task manager which splits tasks that run for a maximum of 6 ms. So i split this decoding function into iterations that take ~6 ms. This way i can render at 60 fps and also decode images at the same time without making the application stutter.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is not possible in standard C, because you want to inspect the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (and the standard does not know it, and some implementations might not have one). You need to read about [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation).

Notice that some function calls can be inlined by an optimizing compiler (in particular link-time-optimization, by compiling & linking with `gcc -flto -O2`) then your question does not make any sense.

If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as your C compiler (and if you don't disable frame pointers and don't ask the compiler to optimize too much) you might consider using GCC [return address builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html).

Look also at Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libbacktrace) inside GCC.

If using a system with [GNU glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (e.g. many Linux systems), you might consider using [backtrace](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) function.

I don't recommend doing all this. It is error-prone, quite Linux/Glibc/GCC specific, and optimization-adverse.

Since you are using a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) library, you should better improve it yourself to fit your needs. You'll better also publish your changes and try to push them upstream.